# Push notifications with Firebase and Titanium studio

Tags: android, firebase, titanium, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can I integrate my app with Firebase to send push notifications? I have done it once with GCM, but GCM was replaced by Firebase.

```
var Notification = require("notifications");
var Cloud = require("ti.cloud");

Cloud.Users.login({
    login : "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    password : "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}, function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        var user = e.users[0];
        console.log("User registered!!");
        if (Ti.Platform.osname != "android") {
            Notification.registerIOS();
        } else {
            Notification.registerAndroid();
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Error registering user!!", e);
    }
});
```

My login and password I take from the tiapp.xml file:

```
<property name="acs-username-development" type="string"> XXXXXXXXXXXXX </property>  
<property name="acs-password-development" type="string"> XXXXXXXXXXXXX </property>
```

Im getting always the error :

```
Error registering user!! {"success":false,"error":true,"code":401,"message":"401 Unauthorized request. Please provide a valid App key or Oauth key."}
```

Why did this worked in the past but is not working now? I have registered my project to Firebase and have registered my project key by titanium studio.

Comment: you're trying to use `ti.cloud` not Firebase

Comment: ti.cloud is wat is used in titanium. titanium dose then the intercommunication between ti.cloud and firebase. But I have already figured not how to put this to work

Comment: Hey Manuel_Rodrigues, could you share the solution with me ? I'm stuck in same situation

Comment: are you programming in titanium Maverick ?